# How to check if a string contains specific format in python?

Tags: string, python-3.x, format, include, contain

For example, in python 3, I want to check if a string contains `_{}P_`, { } can be any number like `_5P_`, `_10P_`? Should I use re?

Comment: `import re;re.match("_\d+P_",'_10P_')`

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.search`

```
import re
if re.search(r'_\d+P_', your_string):
    print ('String contains pattern _[digits]P_')
```